# The only option is to include that block of code into each of my functions?

Tags: javascript, firefox, scope, universalxpconnect

Several of my functions require the `UniversalXPConnect` privilege to be enabled.

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect');
```

So, my functions look like this:

```
function oneOfMyFunctions() {
    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect');

    // ...
}
```

Actually, I also `try` to `catch` the exception when the privilege is denied. Looks as follows:

```
try {
    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect');

    // ...
} catch (e) {
    // ...
}
```

I'd rather to make that a separate function and call it from within my functions as follows:

```
function oneOfMyFunctions() {
    if (enablePrivilege()) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Given that the `enablePrivilege` function would be as follows:

```
function enablePrivilege() {
    try {
        netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect');
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

But, for security reasons, that is impossible as the privilege is granted only in the scope of the requesting function.

So, the only option is to include that block of code into each of my functions?

**UPDATE:**

As I am going to also `try` to `catch` some other exceptions I've ended up with the following design:

```
function readFile(path, start, length) {
    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect');

    var file = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/file/local;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    file.initWithPath(path);

    var istream = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/network/file-input-stream;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileInputStream);
    istream.init(file, -1, -1, false);

    istream.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsISeekableStream);
    istream.seek(0, start);

    var bstream = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/binaryinputstream;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIBinaryInputStream);
    bstream.setInputStream(istream);

    return bstream.readBytes(length);
}

var filepath = 'C:\\test.txt', start = 440, length = 5;

try {
    console.log(readFile(filepath, start, length));
} catch (e) {
    if (e.name == 'Error') console.log('The privilege to read the file is not granted.');
    else console.log('An error happened trying to read the file.');
}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you look into not using enablePrivilege at all.  It's deprecated and on its way to being removed.

Comment: Interesting... Could you please post a link where it is stated so?

Comment: And what would be the replacement then?

Comment: The replacement is using an extension.  I'm not sure how clearly documented this is, but upcoming Firefox versions will warn when you use enablePrivilege, and you can no longer use enablePrivilege to do cross-site XMLHttpRequest.  There's mention of this in some places (e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mochitest#How_can_I_get_around_the_error_.22Permission_denied_to_get_property_XPCComponents.classes.22.3f ) but a lot more documentation to update yet.

Comment: I'm planning for some functionality with file I/O that does require that privilege. And, as it turns out, it may not work in the future... Well, sad to hear that. Anyway, thanks for informing me!

Comment: As I said, you'd just want to use an extension instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make enablePrivilege a sort of wrapper function that accepts a function as a parameter that it then calls inside itself, like so

```
function enablePrivilege(funcParam) {
    //enable privileges, in try-catch
    funcParam();
}
```

so that when you call it like so

```
enablePrivilege(oneOfMyFunctions);
```

the function that needs the privileges should have them since it is called inside the scope of enablePrivilege.

Comment: That's an idea for sure! Thanks!